# Loss of image color when I use PIL convert on numpy array (image)

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use PIL with numpy array and then find the dominant color. First, my image is a numpy array (28,28) and is not read from a file. I use the following code to get the dominant color from that image.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
myimage=np.random.randint(255,size=(28,28))
image = Image.fromarray(myimage,mode="P") # I use mode=P because if I didn't I will get an error in the next line.
result = image.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=1)
result.putalpha(0)
colors = result.getcolors()
```

Now `colors` is always black `[(784,(14,14,14,0)]`, however, if I saved `myimage` to a file and use `image=Image.open(myimage.png)` I get the correct `colors=[(5807904, (222, 158, 23, 0))]`. Any ideas why is that happening and how to fix it. The reason I am not saving the image to a files first is because of efficiency measures because I have thousands of images that I loop within them.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you modify the example in your question so that we can run it? For example, importing PIL and generating an example array for `myimage`. `np.random` might help.

Comment: 1. Are you accidentally saving the original image? 2. If your goal is to get the dominant color, `Image.getcolors()` returns "an unsorted list of (count, pixel) values". Is the dominant color not the color with the highest count?

Comment: Ok, here you go.

Comment: @Jarad 1. what do you mean by original images. 2. I only get a list with 1 object because I chose `colors=1`.

Answer (score 0):

The image generated with your code does not contain color data, so no wonder you don't get them. `image` should be created with:

```
# note the final '4' indicating the number of channels
# 4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB, 1 for grayscale
myimage = np.random.randint(255, size=(28, 28, 4))
image = Image.fromarray(myimage, mode='RGBA')
```

This now simulates a random color image with alpha channel.

Now the rest of the code is a mystery to me, in the sense that I don't know exactly what you expect, but from my tests on an image loaded from disk and from the simulated data I get similar results:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc

# for reproducible results
np.random.seed(0)

def _calc(pil_image):
    result = pil_image.convert(mode='P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=1)
    result.putalpha(0)
    colors = result.getcolors()
    print(colors)

myimage = np.random.randint(255, size=(28, 28, 3))
image = Image.fromarray(myimage, mode='RGBA')
_calc(image)

myimage = np.random.randint(255, size=(28, 28, 4))
image = Image.fromarray(myimage, mode='RGBA')
_calc(image)

myimage = scipy.misc.face(False)
image = Image.fromarray(myimage, mode='RGB')
_calc(image)


import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve(
    'https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png',
    'python-logo.png')
image = Image.open('python-logo.png')
_calc(image)
```

And I obtain, I believe correctly:

```
[(784, (6, 0, 0, 0))]
[(784, (7, 0, 0, 0))]
[(786432, (111, 118, 102, 0))]
[(23780, (254, 254, 254, 0))]
```